# How to output markdown with CKEditor 5?

Tags: ckeditor5

I've been trying to output markdown with CKEditor 5 but I can't figure it out how to do it, how can I output markdown instead of html?
So far I have tried:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/34.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
var myEditor;
ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( 'textarea.editor' ),{
            plugins: [Bold,Italic, Markdown],
            toolbar:['bold', 'italic', 'markdown'],
        } )
        .then( editor => {
            console.log( 'Editor was initialized', editor );
            myEditor = editor;
        } )
        .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
        } );
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Markdown plugin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/markdown.html) isn't added by default into the classic editor. You could create a custom editor with the [Online Builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/) and include "Markdown" to get what you need.